# Cannot connect to iTunes Store (in Sandbox mode)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-simulator, in-app-purchase

I'm experiencing this error when I try to buy a product in sandbox mode in my application.

I'm getting the error in the simulator ios 5.0 and also on the device ios 5.0.

I've checked the IDs and they are correct, because the products return to my application correctly, I can see them in the selling product list but I can't buy them because it gives me an error. A code 0 error that correspond to a Unkown Error Code.

I've also done a reset on the simulator and the device.

The purchase fails before asking me the test account.

Anyone is experiencing this kind of error? It seems to be a server error because a few days ago (before the servers closed) the same code works well.

Comment: this is too localized and too much of a discussion. please take it to chat.

Comment: Do you get an instance of SKProduct when you send off an SKProductsRequest, or are they listed as unknown product IDs in the callback?

Comment: The problem isn't with SKProducts, they are listed correctly. It's when I submit the purchase request that I get the error

Comment: The sandbox servers are down for the holidays. Try again after iTunes connect is back up. This happens every year.

Comment: @Jason you should make your comment an answer.  I'd vote for it because it's useful and seems to be the correct answer to the question here.

Comment: @Sam I kinda agree with Daniel, I think this question is too localized and should be closed actually. It's only helpful for a couple of days during the holiday and there's no telling if it will happen again next year.

Comment: @Jason I've been back and forth on this question.  I like this question because I can cite it to the managers / testers / product owners at my company who are currently asking me why all the sudden our sandbox in-app purchasing doesn't work.

Comment: One of the testers here reported that in-app-purchasing is working again.